# Find different intergrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find two diffenrent integrating factor of $$3x(y^2-1)dx+2y(x^2+1)dy=0$$

I can only find the $\frac{1}{(y^2-1)(x^2+1)}$, Is it any other integrating factor?

Comment: Let $Pdx+Qdy=dH$ be  an exact differential equation. that is "1" is an integrating factor! Hence for every $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ the function $f'\circ H$ is an integrating factor too. So multiply your integrating factor to your initial equation to obtain a complete differential dH hence you have  a lot of  alternatives integrating factor in the form $f'(H)$ for arbitrary f.

Comment: You can multiply it by any constant it will also work

Comment: for example $x^2+y^2$ is  an integrating factor for $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(xdx+ydy$ so we get $xdx+ydy=d(x^2+y^2)=dH) so cos(x^2+y^2) is another one

Comment: f'(H) multiply your initial integrating factor is  a  new  inw integrating factor

Comment: Thank you very much for this inspiring answer!:D@AliTaghavi

Comment: @red_rose you are wellcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3x(y^2-1)dx+2y(x^2+1)dy=0$$
Your integrating factor looks good to me. You can multiply it by any constant it will also work.
$$3(y^2-1)d(x^2+1)+2(x^2+1)d(y^2-1)=0$$
Substitute $u=x^2+1$ and $v=y^2-1$:
$$3vdu+2udv=0$$
Divide by $uv$:
$$\dfrac {3du}{u}+\dfrac {2dv}{v}=0$$
Integrate.

---

Another integrating factor
$$3vdu+2udv=0$$
Multiply by $u^2v$:
$$3u^2v^2du+2u^3vdv=0$$
$$v^2du^3+u^3dv^2=0$$
$$d(u^3v^2)=0$$
Integrate.
$$u^3v^2=C$$
$$(x^2+1)^3(y^2-1)^2=C$$